# How would an extra moon affect the tides?

Tags: moons, ocean

In my world, I'm planning to add a second moon which would be positioned closely to the first.

I was wondering what effect would that have on the tides?

Comment: Your second moon can’t be “positioned closely to the 1st”. It will have to have its own orbit, with a different orbital period, so it will sometimes be near the current Moon and sometimes on the opposite side of the Earth.

Comment: @Mike Scott Provided they were different enough in mass, the small one could be at a relative lagrangian point I think, and thus have the same orbital path. But then it would be far I think and not much of a moon.

Comment: This is a subset of the question linked to by @Renan, and the answer there (which is good) applies here as well.